# How to use the value of standardFieldProps in an Odoo Owl component?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-16, odoo-owl

I am trying to use a new owl component in an existing Odoo app, following the tutorial [here:](https://codingdodo.com/create-field-widget-in-owl-odoo-16/).

I want to display the contents of the field in the view but the field actually contains some JSON so I want to process it in the Javascript of the component first.

I am able to add the raw content of the field to the DOM using:

```
import { standardFieldProps } from "@web/views/fields/standard_field_props";
```

and

```
MyField.props = standardFieldProps;
```

Then in the template I can see the JSON object using:

```
<pre t-esc="props.value" class="bg-primary text-white p-3 rounded"/>
```

However if I try to add the standardFieldProps to the state:

```
state = useState({ props: standardFieldProps });
```

The value of `state.props.value` is `true`, rather than the value of the JSON object.

I have tried logging the value of the props in different Hooks (onWillStart, onMounted, onWillrender) but it is always `true`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `props` are easily found at `this.props`. I'm not sure why the tutorial above imports `@web/views/fields/standard_field_props` but as far as I can see it is unnecessary. I can access `this.props` from the `setup()` method and add it to the state from there:

```
import { Component, useState} from "@odoo/owl";
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
export class MyField extends Component {
    static template = "my_app.my_field";
    setup() {
      this.state = useState({ props: this.props});
       ...
```